# Add nested code infinite times

Tags: c#, json.net, nested-loops

I have a unique issue. My program is getting bookmarks from chrome, from a Bookmarks JSON file. I am using the JSON.net dll for this. My issue is, is that I need to get each URL in its correct folder hierarchy, however, it seems that you can create an infinate amount of folders to hold the bookmarks in. Here is an example of the JSON hiarchy:

```
{
   "checksum": "c9e24e7fb3c6cb184fb776e32dd1004e",
   "roots": {
      "bookmark_bar": {
         "children": [ {
{
"children": [ {
   "children": [ {
      "children": [ {
         "children": [ {
            "date_added": "12985566069697953",
            "id": "225",
            "name": "EvasiveURL",
            "type": "url",
            "url": "evasiveurl.com"
         } ],
         "date_added": "12991165233108137",
         "date_modified": "12991165244676611",
         "id": "374",
         "name": "NestedFolder2",
         "type": "folder"
      } ],
      "date_added": "12991165215985934",
      "date_modified": "12991165215985934",
      "id": "373",
      "name": "NestedFolder",
      "type": "folder"
   } ],
   "date_added": "12985566069695953",
   "date_modified": "12991165219618934",
   "id": "204",
   "name": "Games",
   "type": "folder"
}
```

And here is my current code:

```
for (int i = 0; o["roots"]["bookmark_bar"]["children"][i] != o["roots"]["bookmark_bar"]["children"].Last; i++)
{
    var property = o["roots"]["bookmark_bar"]["children"][i]["url"];
    var property2 = o["roots"]["bookmark_bar"]["children"][i]["children"];
    Console.WriteLine(o["roots"]["bookmark_bar"]["children"][i]["type"]);
    if (o["roots"]["bookmark_bar"]["children"][i]["type"].ToString() == "url") {
        Console.WriteLine("URL");
    }

    else if (o["roots"]["bookmark_bar"]["children"][i]["type"].ToString() == "folder")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("FOLDER");
        for (int ii = 0; o["roots"]["bookmark_bar"]["children"][i]["children"][ii] != o["roots"]["bookmark_bar"]["children"][i]["children"].Last; ii++)
        {
            property = o["roots"]["bookmark_bar"]["children"][i]["children"][ii];
          //  Console.WriteLine(property);
            if (o["roots"]["bookmark_bar"]["children"][i]["type"].ToString() == "url")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("URL");
            }

            else if (o["roots"]["bookmark_bar"]["children"][i]["type"].ToString() == "folder")
            {
                for (int iii = 0; o["roots"]["bookmark_bar"]["children"][i]["children"][ii]["children"][iii] != o["roots"]["bookmark_bar"]["children"][i]["children"][ii]["children"].Last; iii++)
                {
                    if (o["roots"]["bookmark_bar"]["children"][i]["type"].ToString() == "url")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("URL");
                    }
                    else if (o["roots"]["bookmark_bar"]["children"][i]["type"].ToString() == "folder")
                    {
                        //etc. etc.
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, how can I rewrite this code, without copy/pasting the previous for loops and If-Else statements into where I said 'etc. etc'?

Thanks!

Edit: This is class o:

```
JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
var o = (JToken)serializer.Deserialize(jsonReader);
```

Comment: Such problems are solved with recursive function calls

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would be a solution for your problem. As I said you process childs recursive.

```
private void processJsonInput()
{
  var reader = new StreamReader(new FileStream("d:\\jsonfile.txt", FileMode.Open));

  JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
  var o = (JToken)serializer.Deserialize(new JsonTextReader(reader));

  foreach (var child in o["roots"]["bookmark_bar"]["children"])
  {
    processChild(child);
  }
}

private void processChild(JToken child)
{
  if (child["type"].ToString() == "url")
  {
    Console.WriteLine("URL");
  } 
  else if (child["type"].ToString() == "folder")
  {
    Console.WriteLine("FOLDER");
    // process sub childrens in the folder
    foreach (var subChild in child["children"])
    {
      processChild(subChild);
    }
  }
}
```